# Equation of a Circle Mobius Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

I am able to prove that w= $e^{i\theta}$ $\frac{z+\alpha}{1+\bar{\alpha} z}$ maps circles to circles for a given problem, however I am not to familiar with this particular equation, I would appreciate any cite or book or name for this particular equation of a circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any standard text on complex analysis will have this equation.  For example Ahlfors - 
Complex Analysis or Conway's - Functions of One Complex Variable.